# Amend with bond to new data shows unexpected behaviour

Tags: j

I have been using J for a couple of weeks now and recently started using it for simple problems rather than just toying with concepts.

This problem needs to replace all `x` characters in a string into `y`, which works but using a dyad form of the final verb gives me unexpected output.

Let's use the following example input:

```
input =. 'abcxdefxghi'
```

First, I need to find the indexes of `x` characters in the right argument for amend.

```
findx =. I.@:([:'x'&= ])
findx input   NB. 3 7
0 findx input NB. 3 7
1 findx input NB. 3 7
```

Then, I amend the results of `findx` with a bonded `y` on the left.

```
trxy =. 'y'&(findx })
trxy input     NB. abcydefyghi
_1 trxy input  NB. domain error
0 trxy input   NB. abcxdefxghi <= this is the really unexpected result
1 trxy input   NB. abcydefyghi <= somewhat unexpected, works with strictly positive ints
'a' trxy input NB. domain error
```

There is two things I don't understand:

- why `trxy` sometimes works as a dyad when I thought I bonded the left side of my amend ?
- why a `0` left argument stops `trxy` from working ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With `1 trxy input` you are executing `1 'y'&(findx }) input` – and `x u&n y` is maybe not what you expect. It is documented (somewhat hidden) on the bottom of this page: https://code.jsoftware.com/wiki/Vocabulary/ampm

It is equivalent to `x (m&n @ ] ^: [) y`, thus applies `n` on `y` (with `m` on the left side) for `x` times. That's why with `0 trxy y` you aren't executing anything, thus `y` stays the same. With `1 trxy y` you are applying `trxy` once to `y`. As `trxy` has no trivial inverse, `_1 trxy y` results in an error. And because `'a'` isn't a number, the last one is just a plain error.

If you – for whatever reason – just want to be able to write `trxy` as a monad and a dyad that ignores the left-hand side, you could use `trxy =. 'y' findx} ]`. (As you could also use `findx =. I.@:('x' = ])` or just `findx =. [:I. 'x'=]`.)

Comment: That makes a lot of sense thank you very much, and indeed I had not seen this amp dyad. The monad/dyad is great and definitely works for my use case. I’m still going to try tacit monad, and might comment again if I get nowhere.